# Determine lines that intersect a polygon in R

Tags: r, polygon, spatial

I have a dataset that has 1,000's of lines that I can overlay on a section land map (Sec, Township, Range).  I need to identify and collect the names of sections that have which lines crossing them.

I am able to find a single point in a polygon but not a line.  The line can traverses multiple sections.  I think I need a loop to do this but I am having trouble with it.

I have an example that might help describe what I am trying to achieve.

Any help would be greatly apprecieated!

[image]

Comment: Hi mfarr. Are you able to tell us a bit more? Do you have the perimeter lines for the polygons?

Comment: Hi Allan, very good question. Not entirely sure but I believe so.

Comment: if you have the perimeter lines then you can check whether your other lines intersect them arithmetically.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the suggestion. I will check if u have them and work on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have your polygons and lines in a standard format you can use `st_intersects`
from the `sf` package. Below is an example using three counties of North Carolina as
polygons.

Load `sf`:

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.2, PROJ 6.2.1
```

Make polygonal data (disclaimer: for quick illustration geographical longitude,latitude
coordinates are used here, but really planar projected coordinates should be used):

```r
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"), quiet = TRUE)
n <- 3
poly_dat <- st_sf(poly_id = LETTERS[1:n], nc$geometry[1:n])
```

Make line data:

```r
line1 <- st_linestring(rbind(c(-81.8,36.5),c(-80.5,36.5)))
line2 <- st_linestring(rbind(c(-81,36.3),c(-80.5,36.3)))
line_dat <- st_sf(linename = c("1", "2"), geometry = st_sfc(line1, line2, crs = st_crs(poly_dat)))
```

Plot:

```r
plot(poly_dat, reset = FALSE)
plot(line_dat, add = TRUE, col = 1:2, lty = 2)
legend("topright", legend = paste("Line", 1:2), col = 1:2, lty = 2)
```

[image]

Find intersections:

```r
st_intersects(line_dat, poly_dat)
#> although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_intersects assumes that they are planar
#> Sparse geometry binary predicate list of length 2, where the predicate was `intersects'
#>  1: 1, 2, 3
#>  2: 3
```

Comment: Thank for the solution.  exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Great @mfarr. You might want to accept the answer by clicking the check mark, so it turns green and appears as solved for future searches.